# Menu buttons only sometimes make click sound

Tags: android

Menu buttons will always make a click sound if I press quickly after activity loaded e.g. press then back then press again but if I stay on menu for more than a few seconds they will most likely not play a sound. Method in my on click listeners below:

```
private void playSound() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("Sound",true)) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.menuclick);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a new MediaPlayer in each click.  Make a media player one time at startup, and reuse it for each click.

Comment: Should the mp.start(); be at the end? What if the Media player finishes before the OnCompletionListener can be set